# Broadcom BCM4356 driver

Tags: wireless, broadcom

I just received a lenovo T460S with Broadcom 4356 wireless adapter.

Is there any driver available for this adapter ?

I tried the traditionnal `bcmwl-kernel-source` package but it did not work.

Do you know if there is any official driver available somewhere or if any other broadcom driver would work ?

Thanks :)

```
$ lspci -vvnn | grep -A9 Network
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4356 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43ec] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:0777]
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 18
    Region 0: Memory at f1400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Region 2: Memory at f1000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>


$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.10
Release:    15.10
Codename:   wily

$ uname -a
Linux gimly 4.2.0-30-generic #35-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 19 13:52:26 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 5):

Your device is covered by the driver *brcmfmac* in Ubuntu 15.10. It also requires firmware that is included in *linux-firmware-1.149* and later. Let's install the latest firmware first. Download this package to any convenient place. https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/1.156/+build/9020816/+files/linux-firmware_1.156_all.deb Right-click it and select 'Open with Ubuntu Software Center' and install it.

Now open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe -r brcmfmac
```

The last command may end in an error; that's fine, just continue:

```
sudo modprobe brcmfmac
```

The wireless should now be working.

Comment: It is not a very good idea to download to desktop. Non-English users will not find the file in `~/Desktop`.

Comment: And also `bcmwl-kernel-source` should be removed. It blacklists `brcmfmac`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running a Lenovo T560 with Broadcom 4356 on Kubuntu 18.04.1 LTS and using linux-firmware_1.156, wireless works. But, when updating packages, all newer linux-firmware in use, disconnected me from wireless.

So I just followed the steps mentioned above and afterwards, I put the package on hold:

```
sudo apt-mark hold linux-firmware
```

Thus, the package stays at the same version (1.156).

At some point there may be linux-firmware, that supports Broadcom 4356 again, then simply replace "hold", with "unhold" in that CLI command and then run the update.