# BCM4356 (brcmfmac) on ThinkPad T560 sees networks but rejects password

Tags: drivers, wireless, broadcom, thinkpad

I have a ThinkPad T560 with Broadcom wifi card:

```
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM4356 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43ec] (rev 02)
```

It is not covered in [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers/60395#60395). Following this topic by installing `firmware-b43-installer` and `linux-firmware` does not help.

On Ubuntu 17.10 it gets the proper driver (brcmfmac), sees my wireless networks but refuses to connect to any that are protected with WPA/WPA2 - it just keeps asking for the password.

dmesg show something like this which is a bit weird:

```
[ 8126.093543] brcmfmac 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac4356-pcie.txt failed with error -2
[ 8126.530782] brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware version = wl0: Oct 22 2015 06:16:41 version 7.35.180.119 (r594535) FWID 01-1a5c4016
[ 8126.652096] brcmfmac 0000:04:00.0 wlp4s0: renamed from wlan0
```

I tried to download `brcmfmac4356-pcie.txt` file from some linux-firmware related site but that didn't help (although the line disappeared from dmesg)

This problem is super-frustrating as I remember I found a solution when 17.10 was launched but I cannot find it now.

On Ubuntu 18.04 LTS the card doesn't work at all.

Comment: I have a Lenovo T560 and following the steps mentioned in: https://askubuntu.com/questions/739676/broadcom-bcm4356-driver it's running Kubuntu 18.04.1 LTS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Broadcom BCM4356 driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/739676/broadcom-bcm4356-driver)

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar situation with the brcmfmac driver and achieve a connection by going to the terminal immediately after logging in and entering;
`sudo modprobe -r brcmfmac`
Then wait a couple of seconds and enter;
`sudo modprobe brcmfmac`
You might have to forget the connection, re-add it ticking start automatically and then reboot and try the commands again.
Also read about the naming of firmware files for your chipset [here](https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware)